# RunTime Error when trying to add borders to spinner

Tags: java, android

I tried adding borders to a spinner.

Here is the xml res/drawable/spinner_background.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item><layer-list>
        <item><shape>
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#f58218" />
            <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
        </shape></item>
        <item >
            <bitmap android:gravity="right|center" android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_downward_black_24dp" />
        </item>
    </layer-list></item>
</selector>
```

And here is the spinner

```
  <Spinner
                                android:id="@+id/marketSpinner"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"></Spinner>
```

@drawable/ic_arrow_downward_black_24dp is a vector resource.

I get this error at run time

```
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #9: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:771)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:731)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1229)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:282)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:196)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1229)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:188)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:116)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1229)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1202)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
            ... 57 more
```

Comment: Is `ic_arrow_downward_black_24dp` a vector resource?

Comment: Is your png image ic_arrow_downward_black_24dp is in correct folder and in correct format?

Comment: @BenP. yes it is.